# netsh advfirewall import resets connections

Tags: windows, windows-firewall, netsh

On Window Server 2022, if I run this:

```
netsh advfirewall export"C:\firewall-rules.wfw"
```

then, straight away run this:

```
netsh advfirewall import "C:\firewall-rules.wfw"
```

Meaning I export all current rule, then without changing any rules, import the same rule set, Windows Server 2022 resets active connections.

Is there a way to do `netsh advfirewall import "C:\firewall-rules.wfw"`, without resetting active connections?